# How to show a block on specific content type and combine it with path restrictions

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

How do I show a block on all nodes of content type A, without restricting it to other "pages"? I already have some restrictions based on the path. The problem is that by using the settings under Visibilty > Content Type, the block disappears from other places where the block is defined. I want to combine it with showing this block on all nodes of Content Type A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With D8 you can make multiple instances of the same block, just use Place Block to place another copy of it. Then you can have one display on the specific content types, and the other display on the pages you need.